# Best practice to persist android "home"/"main" activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an android app with one "home" or "main" activity that relies on fragments to accomplish several tasks. This data relies on information retrieved from a server (mine, and presumably a substantial amount by google maps).

I would like to structure my code such that several other activities (ie. preferences) can temporarily take focus before returning to the main activity.

Currently android destroys and recreates the main activity, which means bandwidth is wasted every time.

There are several notable intent flags which 'solve' this problem (`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`), however they only appear to be useful when transitioning back to the main activity, which means I have to `@override` the system behaviour for both `onKeyDown()` and `onBackPressed()`. I would really prefer not to do this in case it causes other issues or eventually becomes deprecated.

Is this safe? Or is the better solution to force my application to create a serialization (savedInstanceState) of the main activity and all fragments anytime another activity temporarily takes the foreground?

Comment: How about the use of launch mode? Google for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using saved instance state is the proper approach here. That will let you persist the information retrieved from the server when the activity gets re-created.

You only need to implement code to save / restore the instance state in the fragment or activity that holds the data. If you want to share that data across all your fragments, you can place it in the activity and add code to save the instance state of the activity. Then you can access the data that's stored in the activity from your fragments with `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getData()`.

For code to save and restore instance state, take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState

If the data you need to persist is really large, you can use a retained fragment instead, as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Another trick for large data objects is to use a singleton class to store the data while the orientation change takes place.

Comment: The data would be inappropriate to turn into key-value pairs. I think the retained fragment is the best solution I've seen so far.

Comment: What kind of data is it?